# What is wrong for Pipeline to throw 'ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)'

Tags: python, pipeline, valueerror

I am stuck on a problem where I am getting ValueError for a Housing dataset.

Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XZ4Mz9rv-UCIJKlxEgPmMeB3geR2U8pw?usp=sharing

```
house_df = pd.read_csv(r"….path….\House_Data.csv")
print(house_df.head(10))
print(house_df.shape)
print(house_df.isnull().sum())
print(house_df.isnull().mean() * 100)
print(house_df['balcony'].mode())
print(house_df['balcony'].median())

imputer1 = house_df['location'].fillna('Whitefield', inplace=True)
imputer2 = house_df['size'].fillna('2 BHK', inplace=True)
imputer3 = house_df['society'].fillna('Others', inplace=True)
imputer4 = house_df['bath'].fillna('2', inplace=True)

for ind, val in enumerate(house_df['total_sqft']):
   if '-' in val:
       temp = val.split('-')
       new_value = (float(temp[0]) + float(temp[-1])) / 2
       house_df['total_sqft'].iloc[ind, :] = new_value

imputer5 = new_value

trf1 = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
   ('imputer1', imputer1),
   ('imputer2', imputer2),
   ('imputer3', imputer3),
   ('imputer4', imputer4),
   ('imputer5', imputer5)
],
    remainder='passthrough'
)
 ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='error', drop='first', sparse=False), ["area_type", "location", "size", "society"]

 trf2 = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
     ('ohe', ohe)],
     remainder='passthrough')

 pipeline = Pipeline([
     ('trf1', trf1),
     ('trf2', trf2),
  ])
  pipeline.fit(house_df) # This is line 53
```

Now, here I am getting the error below:

```
File "….path…./HousePricePrediction/test3.py", line 53, in
pipeline.fit_transform(house_df)
File "….path….\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 426, in fit_transform
Xt = self.fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps) File "….path….\HousePricePrediction\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 355, in _fit *fit_params_steps[name], File "….path….\HousePricePrediction\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py", line 349, in call return self.func(args, **kwargs)
File "….path….\HousePricePrediction\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 893, in _fit_transform_one
res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, *fit_params) File "….path….\HousePricePrediction\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py", line 671, in fit_transform self._validate_transformers() File "….path….\HousePricePrediction\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py", line 324, in _validate_transformers names, transformers, = zip(self.transformers)
**ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)**
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The formatting of the exception isn't quite right. For the sake of readability, could you try to get the newlines and spacing to match the actual error? (Also, don't add extra characters; `**` in a code segment isn't bolding; if you provide it there it needs to be _part of the actual code_).

Comment: That said, at a glance, this probably means that `transformers = [ ('ohe', ohe) ]` is wrong and should have three items instead of two. How does the documentation for the specific version of the library you're using say `transformers` should be defined?